# How to listen on connection interrupt through MongoDB driver

Tags: mongodb

I am using nodejs mongo driver to connect to mongodb instance. The code shown as below.

```
// Retrieve
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

// Connect to the db
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/exampleDb", function(err, db) {
 ...
```

how can I listen on the connection interrupt change. I want to get notify if the connection is broken. Whether MongoDB nodejs driver support it?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do that through driver like below code:

```
db.on('close', (event)=>{

});
```

we can listening on the close event.